# disorder of elements when create CFArrayRef using CFArrayCreate

Tags: arrays, objective-c, core-foundation

When I create a CFArrayRef using CFArrayCreate to contain some CGWindowID; I found the created CFArrayRef has disordered elements, which is not expected.

the input is a NSArray of NSNumbers which containing the elements with type CGWindowID, I want to conver this NSArray to a CFArrayRef for further processing.

```
- (void)getArrayRefForWindowList:(NSArray<NSNumber *>)windowIdList
    {
        int windowCount = (int)windowIdList.count;
        NSLog(@"  to show input Count >>>>>>>> %d",windowCount);
        CGWindowID windowIds[windowCount];
        for(int i=0;i<windowCount;i++)
        {
            windowIds[i] = (CGWindowID)[windowIdList[i] intValue];
            NSLog(@"  to show orignial %d",windowIds[i]);
        }
        void *windowIdsParam = windowIds;
        CFArrayRef windowArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)windowIdsParam, (CFIndex)windowCount, nil);
        for(int i=0;i<windowCount;i++)
        {
            CGWindowID windId = (CGWindowID)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windowArrayRef, i);
            NSLog(@"  to show destination %d",windId);
        }
        NSLog(@"  to show outPut Count<<<<<<<<<%ld",(long)CFArrayGetCount(windowArrayRef));
}
```

I expect that  the windIds will be put into windowArrayRef entirely and orderly. 
But actually, some of the windId is missing, below is the NSLog infomation.
You can see 6405,6395,3919,199 is missing, and the last 4 elements are garbage.
Could anyone help to point out what's error here ?

```
to show input Count >>>>>>>> 8

to show orignial 6410

to show orignial 6405

to show orignial 6400

to show orignial 6395

to show orignial 5432

to show orignial 3919

to show orignial 200

to show orignial 199

to show destination 6410

to show destination 6400

to show destination 5432

to show destination 200

to show destination -272646672

to show destination 1349209287

to show destination -272646640

to show destination 1882819913

to show outPut Count<<<<<<<<< 8
```

Answer (score 1):

`CGWindowID` is typedef'd to `uint32_t`. It's a 32-bit value. `CFArrayCreate()` assumes that the `values` parameter is (quoting from [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1388741-cfarraycreate), emphasis mine):

> A C array of the **pointer-sized** values to be in the new array.

Since you're presumably compiling for 64-bit, a pointer is 64 bits in size, not 32 bits. So, your array elements aren't positioned correctly.

The simplest fix would be to declare your `windowIds` array to be an array of `uintptr_t`, not `CGWindowID`.

Comment: Ken, thanks a lot for quick help, it works perfectly for me. One more help needed is how do we know the "pointer-sized" value refer to 32bit or 64bit ?

Comment: 32- vs. 64-bit is part of the "architecture" that you're building for. On macOS, 32-bit is on its way out and recent versions of Xcode will no longer build for 32-bit. That's why I assumed you're building for 64-bit.